# GRPC Service having memory leak

Tags: c#, grpc, .net-5

I have a c# GRPC service self hosted as Windows service.
It gets loaded with 2.5 GB of data when it starts.
After running a small load test we could see memory increasing to 5 GB at the end of the test, and it doesn't release memory after test is over.

Is there a possible **memory leak in Grpc**?

Regards,
Abhi

Comment: anything is *possible*, but that isn't very useful; if you want to know what is happening: running a memory profiler is the way to go. Note: there are two fundamentally different gRPC implementations available for .NET 5 - so knowing whether you're dealing with the unmanaged Google transport vs the managed Microsoft transport would also be important. However, personally I *suspect* that whatever is happening *probably* involves your code and specific usage. Also note that process memory isn't always the same as used managed memory (memory is not aggressively returned to the OS until needed)

Comment: Are any of your gRPC messages over 85,000 bytes in total? If you are making use of the large object heap (LOH) then that memory is not always released in the way that you would expect.